# How do you add "mean= " to your output, instead of the default [1] in R?

Tags: r

How do you add "mean= " to your output, instead of the default [1] in R?

```
 Test_scores <- c(50,75,80,90,99,93,65,85,95,87) #created matrix
 Hours_studied <- c(.1,.5,.6,1,3,3.5,.5,1,2,2.5)
 grade_study <- cbind(Test_scores,Hours_studied) #combined into one matrix
 return(grade_study)

 summarystat <- function(x) {  #make a function to output the mean, median, sd with the output labeled (ex: mean= )
  print(mean(x)), 
  print (median(x))
  print(sd(x))
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
summarystat <- function(x) {  
  cat(sprintf("The mean is %s\n", mean(x))) 
  cat(sprintf("The median is %s\n", median(x)))
  cat(sprintf("The sd is %s\n", sd(x)))

}

summarystat(grade_study)
```

The output is:

```
The mean is 41.685
The median is 26.75
The sd is 42.5506419643576
```

If you want an "=" sign then you could do:

```
summarystat <- function(x) {  
  cat(sprintf("mean = %s\n", mean(x))) 
  cat(sprintf("median =  %s\n", median(x)))
  cat(sprintf("sd = %s\n", sd(x)))

}

summarystat(grade_study)
```

And the output would be:

```
mean = 41.685
median =  26.75
sd = 42.5506419643576
```